# I'm trying to make an HTTPS request to my Node.js server using Axios, but I keep getting the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error

Tags: node.js, axios, certbot

I'm trying to make an HTTPS request to my Node.js server using Axios, but I keep getting the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error. I've verified that my SSL/TLS certificate files are valid and that my server is configured to use HTTPS, but I still can't seem to make a successful request. Here's my Node.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Middleware to handle CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mydomain(dot)com');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "123.456.789.012",
  user: "myuser",
  port: "3306",
  password: "mypassword",
  database: "mydb",
  ssl: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/private-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/certificate.pem')
  }
});

// Handle database connection errors
db.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', error);
    process.exit(1); // Terminate the application on database connection failure
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to MySQL. Result:', results[0].solution);
  }
});

// ... other routes and handlers

const PORT = 8081;

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/private-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/certificate.pem'),
  ciphers: 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA'
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried having an ssl certificate on my database but nothing happens. I am a beginner at this, I honestly have no idea on what I should do and there seems to be no solution online. I am considering to remove my certbot configuration entirely to return back my website into http and start again. I dont know if my ssl configuration or certificate is wrong or just my backend

Comment: It helps a lot if you also show where the error occurs. I suspect that your MySQL connection isn't TLS-protected, so passing ssl options to the connection data would be wrong.

Comment: I see the error in the console in my browser, 

Login.js:72 
        
       POST https://mydomain(dot)com:8081/verifyGoogleEmail net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My axios call to the database seems to be working when it is on http but it did not work when i configured the domain's ssl using certbot

Comment: A quick search says: "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR defines itself as being caused by the misconfiguration of an SSL certificate. It prevents the browser from creating a secure connection with an SSL-protected website." - Some information about your SSL may help to find out the cause of the error.

Comment: is it possible that my mysql database needs to be secured in order to do the axios call on it?